# other ways to update windows 8.1

Tags: update, 8.1-update-1

Is there no other way to download the update. I really need to download the update. I have been trying to download it for over a month now but it's still not working

Comment: Have you tried Windows Device Recovery Tool? : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12379/windows-10-mobile-device-recovery-tool-faq

Comment: Which update are you having a problem with?